# ios colorWithPatternImage, size of the pattern

Tags: ios, iphone, design-patterns, size

I have juste a little problem with my background made with my pattern. I want to make the background with a pattern (75x75), and if i use the method

```
self.myView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPattern.png"]];
```

It work perfectly, but it used the entire size of the picture. I want to do the same thing but used the pattern with the half size (37x37 it is just for improve the quality).

If you have an idea, it will be very nice.
Thanks.

Comment: You Add MyView in mainView After use the code.

Comment: can't you just resize the image used to that?

Comment: Thank you for your help, your comment permit me to solve the problem, with your advice and in declaring an other image named myPattern@2x.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

1) resize your image with the right size (for me its the half 37x37)
2) declare a new image named "myPattern@2x.png" with the higher quality that you want.(xcode will use the better quality with the retina's screen but with the size of the lower)

Thanks for the answers that guide me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:-

```
UIView *view1= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
     [self.view addSubview:view1];
     view1.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPattern.png"]];
```

Comment: what is that changing?

Comment: Its not that i want to do. With your method i have a view with my pattern image, its just like before but with a smaller view.

Comment: That i want its to resize my pattern, because if i resize myself we can see pixels. I think if its possible to use myPattern@2x.png

Comment: I have resize my picture to 37x37 and i have declare an other picture named myPattern@2x.png (75x75), so it resolve my problem, because i use the better quality resize to 37x37.